# Making JQuery .html() wrap attribute values in single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

JQuery by defaults wraps attribute values in double quotes, it also overrides even if the original html string had single quotes as in this example:

```
$("<div><span class= 'foo' id='foo2' >abc</span></div>").html();
```

Output:

```
<span class="foo" id="foo2">abc</span>
```

I looked up in JQuery documentation, also searched but couldn't find any thing related to this, while I can write a regex replace such as [this](https://regex101.com/r/cIMDV5/2) but I don't want to manipulate HTML with regex for obvious reasons,  ***I was wondering if there is a profound way of achieving this***.

**Edit:**

The reason it is bothering me is at some places in the application there exists codes like `htmlstring.indexOf("attr='value'")` which eventually broke when I did some manipulation in the `htmlstring` by converting it into JQuery object and back to string.

**Edit 2:**

I do not need a solution for the particular problem I stated in my upper edit, I already handled that, what made me ask this question was, is it possible or what is the better way of changing the quote wrapping attributes in HTML.

Comment: Why does it bother you?

Comment: That must be a standard, because every(almost) attribute value is wrapped with double quotes. Inspect any page...

Comment: @TakitIsy - because in the application I am working on has codes like `htmlstring.indexOf("attr='value'")` to check existence of an element, and they are quite more frequent for me to refactor them, and since I made some manipulation using jquery, the quotes changed thus the app broke.

Comment: I could see your concern about single/double quotes because you concat strings: `"'+obj+;"` that's a pain in the arse. If so, use Template Literals. Something like this string: `<div id="'+ID+'">` would be `<div id="${ID}">` and quotes wouldn't need any extra work so long as they are originally valid.

Comment: @Shubanker what if you rather change your search code than bother somewhere else, like so `htmlstring.indexOf('attr="value"')`. But to be honest, this seems strange to me, I mean, do you literally convert your html to string and the search?

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for the tip but the problem is attributes are already populated, I just used jquery to insert some new elements into it and quotes all over the places got changed.

Comment: Shubanker, you should add the fact that you're using `htmlstring.indexOf("attr='value'")` in your question. In my opinion, that piece of code is the problem, not the single or double quotes.

Comment: @seethrough I know it seems strange and I had similar reactions when I saw it, but they exists in many places for me to refactor now.

Comment: @Shubanker Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @seethrough Actully I have already fixed this issue by writing code without using JQuery, but still am curious if their exists a way to achieve the same, as for your suggestion I can't as the such codes exits in many places refactoring them isn't feasible for me as of now.

Answer (score 1):

We have the choice of using single or double quotes for the attributes in HTML but…
… when the page is rendered, they all become double quotes.

I suggest you to use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method instead of using `.indexOf()`.

See the snippet below:

```js
var htmlstring1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1').outerHTML;
var htmlstring2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2').outerHTML;
console.log("string:", htmlstring1);
console.log("string:", htmlstring2, '\n\n');
// Note that attr='value' of myDiv2 becomes attr="value" in console


console.log(`Using .indexOf('attr="value"'): (will always work)`)
if (htmlstring1.indexOf('attr="value"') > -1)
  console.log('Found.');
else console.log('Not found.');

console.log(`Using .indexOf("attr='value'"): (will never work)`)
if (htmlstring1.indexOf("attr='value'") > -1)
  console.log('Found.');
else console.log('Not found.');

console.log(`Using .attr('attr') == 'value'): (a suggestion)`)
if ($('#myDiv1').attr('attr') == 'value')
  console.log('Found.');
else console.log('Not found.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv1" attr="value"></div>
<div id="myDiv2" attr='value'></div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

After your comment, I tried some few things…

As you've talked about in your question, there's a trick here:
When an element string is used by jQuery, it gets normalized with double quotes:

```js
var htmlstring = "<span class='foo' id='foo2'>abc</span>";
console.log(htmlstring);

var htmlparsed = $(htmlstring)[0];
console.log(htmlparsed);

// You could even create a function to handle the normalization of quotes
function norm_quotes(str){
  return $(str)[0];
}
console.log(norm_quotes(htmlstring));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'd suggest you to use your `.indexOf("attr='value'")` on a string *only after* it has been parsed by jQuery.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My apologies, should have mentioned `htmlstring` is a plain string variable and doesn't exists in DOM.

Comment: Also, I don't need a snipped to solve my this particular problem, I already did that, I was curious if it was possible to have a quotes of our choice, but still Thanks a ton for your efforts.

Comment: @Shubanker I've updated my answer with something that may interest you.

Comment: yes, the example is similar to mine in the question, do you think there is a way for the other way round ?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you to use your `.indexOf("attr='value'")` on a string *only after* it has been parsed by jQuery. You could even create a function to handle the normalization of quotes. I've added it in my snippet.